# Render settings for DVD in Vegas Pro

Tags: vegas-pro, render, setup

I've been working on a video project and output should be for DVD.

**Video from camera**:
1920×1080; 50 fps

65 min. after cut

**Software**: Vegas Pro 12.0

I need to render it in the best quality possible, but on the other hand, I need it to be max. 4 GB big in size (because of DVD limitations).

Could you please give me advice for best render settings and format choice?

Comment: What region and final output type do you need? E.g., NTSC or PAL?

Comment: I'm located in Central Europe, so I assume that I need PAL?

Comment: What settings have you tried so far, and what output sizes have you been getting with those settings?

Comment: I've tried using DVD architect - widescreen video stream PAL, output was circa 3 GB large, but quality was awful

Comment: are you authoring a DVD or saving a video file on DVD media to be played on a computer?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, but my problem is now out-of-date. I solved it somehow and after a year, I don't recall how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use variable bitrate to cut down on filesize
- 4 GB / 65 min = 8.2 Mb/s which is in the norm for DVD quality so fixed bitrate should be fine. [The max DVD data bitrate is 10.08 Mb/s anyway.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD-Video#Data_rate)

Comment: Funny this answer has not been accepted, is the math too complex? Also, DVD does not support 50p, so need to re-encode into 25i. But then again DVD Architect should do it automatically. Not sure how the quality is "awful" - does the OP preview interlaced resulting video on a computer without deinterlacing?

Answer (score 0):

If you captured at 50 fps, stick to 50 fps or 25 fps, otherwise Vegas will have to pulldown / interpolate / invent frames to go to 60 / 30 fps.

If all (most) of your footage is in Full HD (1080p 50fps), leave your Vegas project with this frame size.

If you are authoring a DVD, you should not determine the bitrate, but rather let DVD Architect determine automatic settings.

Answer (score -1):

Your DVD authoring software should do this automatically. If you’ve got DNxHD (cross platform free) use something in the middle or higher range codecs. Take that nice HD file & let the software crunch it into the needed mpeg TS file.

As for the DVD spec it’s mpeg2 either PAL 720x576 interlaced 25fps or NTSC 720x480 interlaced both are upper field first. If your exporting from a lower field first source like dv pal deinterlace befoe export. The bit rate is technically 10mbps but you need to leave 1mbps for audio (. Remember to encode your DVD audio to ac3 to maximise the bit rate available for video. Also use a 2 pass Variable Bit Rate for best results.